# javascript setMonth() wrong results for the second year

Tags: javascript

For m = range 1-12 it works as expected, increasing month by 1.
For m = range 13- it doesn't work as expected, increasing year by 1.

As `m exceeds 12 inside loop` I was expecting result:

```
Sun Feb 28 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (GET)
Tue Mar 28 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (GET)
Sat Apr 28 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (GET)
```

Instead I get:

```
Sun Feb 28 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (GET)
Tue Mar 28 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (GET)
Sat Apr 28 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0400 (GET)
```

...

```
var loanAmount = 3800,
    loanInterest = 32, // %
    loanDuration = 48, // Month
    loanGrace = 0,
    loanFee = 1, // %
    loanInitMonth = 0,
    loanInitDay = 28,
    loanInitYear = 2014;

var loanStart = new Date(loanInitYear,loanInitMonth,loanInitDay);

for (var m = loanInitMonth; m < loanDuration; m++) {
    var d = loanStart;
    d.setMonth(m);
    console.log(m);
    console.log(d);
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kyyx/2/)

As setMonth description states:

> If a parameter you specify is outside of the expected range, setMonth
>   attempts to update the date information in the Date object
>   accordingly. For example, if you use 15 for monthValue, the year will
>   be incremented by 1 (year + 1), and 3 will be used for month.

I'm obviously not getting this behavior.

Browser Chrome.

Comment: Please reformulate this question. It's hard to understand it.

Comment: [If a parameter you specify is outside of the expected range, setMonth attempts to update the date information in the Date object accordingly. For example, if you use 15 for monthValue, the year will be incremented by 1 (year + 1), and 3 will be used for month.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth)

Comment: @Dr.Molle exactly! By that logic m = 14 should be Mar 2015. Instead I get Mar 2017.

Comment: @Dr.Molle - but the problem he demonstrated is that it is not incrementing it by 1 year, but by (m%12) years.

Comment: see Guffa's answer, he is always using the same date-object, so when m is >11 the year will be incremented, the next loop will use the date-object with the updated year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this, you are copying the reference to the Date object instead of creating a new copy of the object:

```
var d = loanStart;
```

Then, when you change the date in the `d` variable, you are also changing the date in the `loanStart` variable, as it's the same object.

Create a copy of the Date object:

```
var d = new Date(loanStart.getTime());
```

Comment: Or `var d = new Date(+loanStart)`, which is less to type. :-)

Comment: @RobG Or `const d = new Date(loanStart);` which is equivalent to `const d = new Date(loanStart.getTime());`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you aren't adding the time to the *original* date, you're adding it to the *current* date. So setting the month > 12 to the current date will always add at least one year, which will increment the year.

You have two solutions:

1. Make sure you're always modifying the original date by maintaining a copy of that date.
2. Do real date math - trying to set the month (and rely on side-effects) when what you really want to do is increment the month makes for rather confusing code and will have edge cases when, for example, the day of the month isn't a valid day for that month.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing m to setMonth, do d.setMonth(d.getMonth()+1) like below:

```
var loanAmount = 3800,
    loanInterest = 32, // %
    loanDuration = 48, // Month
    loanGrace = 0,
    loanFee = 1, // %
    loanInitMonth = 0,
    loanInitDay = 28,
    loanInitYear = 2014;

var loanStart = new Date(loanInitYear,loanInitMonth,loanInitDay);

for (var m = loanInitMonth; m < loanDuration; m++) {
    var d = loanStart;
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth()+1);
    console.log(m);
    console.log(d);
}
```